# ScrollView com um Container Fixo no Rodapé - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Gostaria de um ScrollView com um container fixo no rodapé pois nele vou posicionar um banner da admob porem não consigo fixar esse container quero que ele seja independente do scrollview e fique sempre fixo na tela porem não obtive sucesso, um exemplo de como deveria ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu codigo atual:

```
LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: constraints.copyWith(
                minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
                maxHeight: double.infinity,
              ),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, right: 18, top: 15, bottom: 15),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Text(
                        "Ferramentas",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF808080),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 0.5,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: Colors.black38,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: ResponsiveGridRow(
                        children: [
                          ResponsiveGridCol(
                            xs: 6,
                            xl: 2,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => GasolinaXAlcool(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 110,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'images/gasolina.png',
                                      width: 50,

                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Gasolina ou Álcool?',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ResponsiveGridCol(
                            xs: 6,
                            xl: 2,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => QuantoGasto(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 110,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'images/moedas.png',
                                      width: 50,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Quanto vou gastar?',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ResponsiveGridCol(
                            xs: 6,
                            xl: 2,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => MediaSimples(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 110,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'images/grafico.png',
                                      width: 50,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Média de Consumo / \n\ KM Percorrido',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ResponsiveGridCol(
                            xs: 6,
                            xl: 2,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => MediaCompleta(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 110,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'images/mediagrafico.png',
                                      width: 50,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Média de Consumo / \n\ KM Inicial / Final',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ResponsiveGridCol(
                            xs: 6,
                            xl: 2,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Premium(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 110,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'images/avalie.png',
                                      width: 50,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Seja Premium \n\ (Remove anúncios)',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red
                            ),
                          ) // Your footer widget
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }));
  }
}
```

Tentei dessa forma porém o container fica dependendo do scrollview. Se eu giro, o celular fica lá pra baixo e não gostaria disso. Preciso que ele fique fixo no bottom, não sendo dependente do scrollview para que fique sempre visível.

Comment: O básico dessa abordagem é fazer a separação dos componentes. A tela de 2 filhos, então ela tem uma `Column`. O primeiro é o componente com a rolagem, o segundo é seu botão. Como vc deseja fixar o botão no final o outro componente precisa ocupar o restante do espaço da tela. Eu tentaria simplesmente envolver o primeiro com um `Expanded`. Dependendo dos componentes que for utilizar pode gerar algum conflito mas da pra resolver lendo as mensagens que o log te retorna. Tente algo nessa linha de implementação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei esse exemplo aqui de layout, acredito ser o que deseja:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
                  Container(height: 500, color: Colors.yellow),
                  Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green),
                ],
              )
            ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100, 
              color: Colors.orange, 
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Propagandas chatas do caramba!")
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Pode ser testado aqui no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter).*

**Observações**

Como o *Footer* vai ser um Widget com tamanho fixo não tem porque utilizar o `Expanded` nele, o certo é você utilizar no componente com maior área em seu layout, que normalmente será o Widget responsivo da sua tela.

Assim dependendo das dimensões do celular, o *Footer* permanecerá com o mesmo tamanho sempre, já o `ScrollView` irá se ajustar de acordo com o espaço que sobrar.

Answer (score -1):

Basta utilizar bottomSheet do Scafold.
Será criada uma area na parte inferior da tela para você incluir os widgets que desejar.